Increasing vertical space between footnotes without affecting space between footnote rule and first footnote
This answer from 2009 describes how to increase the vertical space between footnotes; and it works, of course, but it also increases the space between the first footnote and the footnoterule.
Using \setlength{\footnotesep}{0.5cm}
Is there a similar command to adjust this or is a renew command needed, such as:
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
  \hrule width 2in height 0.4pt \vspace*{-2.6pt}}

Adjusting this from -2.6pt to -4.6pt (or whatever the space between footnotes is to be) appears to work, apparently because it runs after the \skip\footlins but I'm speaking beyond my depth here and took this from the LaTeX Comp. 3 text and just modified the last \vspace.
Thank you.
